# How to get stored data in laravel filament afterCreate()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-filament

Laravel filament has afterCreate function that will trigger after data has been stored in the database

```
protected function afterCreate(): void
{
   // Runs after the form fields are saved to the database.
}
```

The question is, how do I get the 'stored' data? I need to save a log for it (in the different table) that require the id of the `stored` data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the created record with `$this->record`.

Also, this property is available in `EditRecord`.

[Here's](https://github.com/filamentphp/demo/blob/main/app/Filament/Resources/Shop/OrderResource/Pages/CreateOrder.php) an example from the filament itself.

Answer (score 0):

**use this to access data:**

```
protected function afterCreate(): void
{

    $storedDataId = $this->record->getKey();
    
    $storedDataField = $this->record->yourFieldName;

}
```